# Aggregate on two columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset with prices of items from different branches of a store that looks a bit like this:

```
Item,Chain,Branch1,Branch2,Branch3
Laptop,Sears,1000,1100,900
Laptop,JCP,1300,900,1200
Laptop,Macys,1500,1800,1700
TV,Sears,800,600,700
TV,JCP,400,600,700
TV,Macys,900,1000,1100
```

What I want: For each unique combination of Item and Chain, calculate the median price from the three branches.

I tried something along the lines of

```
aggregate(data[,3:5], list(data$Item, data$Chain), median)
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: There is only one row for each combination of `Item` and `Chain`

Comment: [tag:aggregate-functions] is a SQL tag

Comment: in base R you could do: `aggregate(Branch~Item+Chain,reshape(data,3:5,dir="long",sep=""),median)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by()` and `summarise()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(Item = c("Laptop","Laptop","Laptop","TV","TV","TV"),
                 Chain = c("Sears","JCP","Macys","Sears","JCP","Macys"),
                 Branch1 = c(1000,1300,1500,800,400,900),
                 Branch2 = c(1100,900,1800,600,600,1000),
                 Branch3 = c(900,1200,1700,700,700,1100))

df %>%
  group_by(Item, Chain) %>%
  summarise(median = median(c(Branch1, Branch2, Branch3)))
```

Comment: You could also `tidyr::gather(Branch, Price, -Item, -Chain)` before grouping, then `summarise(Median = median(Price))`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `aggregate()` aggregates each *column*.

For the sake of completeness, here are some alternative approaches:

#### 1. Base R row-wise `apply()`

```
dat$median <- apply(dat[, 3:5], 1L, median)
dat
```

> ```
>      Item Chain Branch1 Branch2 Branch3 median
> 1: Laptop Sears    1000    1100     900   1000
> 2: Laptop   JCP    1300     900    1200   1200
> 3: Laptop Macys    1500    1800    1700   1700
> 4:     TV Sears     800     600     700    700
> 5:     TV   JCP     400     600     700    600
> 6:     TV Macys     900    1000    1100   1000
> ```

#### 2. `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .(median = median(c(Branch1, Branch2, Branch3))), by = .(Item, Chain)]
```

> ```
>      Item Chain median
> 1: Laptop Sears   1000
> 2: Laptop   JCP   1200
> 3: Laptop Macys   1700
> 4:     TV Sears    700
> 5:     TV   JCP    600
> 6:     TV Macys   1000
> ```

#### 3. `data.table` after reshaping to long format

Following [neilfws' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089224/aggregate-on-two-columns#comment91128805_52089325) to reshape from wide to long format before aggregating:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(dat), c("Item", "Chain"))[, .(median = median(value)), by = .(Item, Chain)]
```

> ```
>      Item Chain median
> 1: Laptop Sears   1000
> 2: Laptop   JCP   1200
> 3: Laptop Macys   1700
> 4:     TV Sears    700
> 5:     TV   JCP    600
> 6:     TV Macys   1000
> ```

#### Data

As `data` and `df` are names of R functions I will use a different name to avoid the risk of hard to debug name clashes:

```
dat <- data.table::fread("
Item,Chain,Branch1,Branch2,Branch3
Laptop,Sears,1000,1100,900
Laptop,JCP,1300,900,1200
Laptop,Macys,1500,1800,1700
TV,Sears,800,600,700
TV,JCP,400,600,700
TV,Macys,900,1000,1100")
```